# net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: UCAExc:::4.0.2 user lacks privilege or object not found: WHERE

Tags: java, sql-server, ms-access, sql-update, sqlconnection

```
public void update(String tempid,String name,String sid,int age,String course,String department) throws SQLException {
    try {
        int result = 0;
        s = con.createStatement();
        result = s.executeUpdate("Update db set Name="+name+", Age="+age+ 
                ",Course=" +course+ ",Department="+department+", where StudentID="+tempid);
        if(result > 0) {
            System.out.println("更新成功");
        }
    }catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally {
        con.close();
    }
}
```

What is the problem of this coding part? Only update command cannot run sucessfully , others like insert,delete,select(sql command) can run sucessfully. Anyone can help me with this problem? Thanks

Comment: Have you tried the `update` command when connected to the database via your IDE?  `insert`, `select`, `delete`, and `update` are all separate privileges.

Comment: Great! You can answer your own question, with the text from your comment, with details on what the issue was (what was missing before) and how your code solved it, and later mark it as accepted to help others searching the site.

Comment: @MarkStewart okay , btw thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by changing my code.
I used PreparedStatement to get the data from input , then update to the database(db) , the error get solved.

```
public void update(String tempid,String name,String sid,int age,String course,String department) throws SQLException {
        try {
            int result = 0;
            PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement("Update db set Name=? , StudentID=? , Age=? , Course=? , Department=? where StudentID=?");
            pst.setString(1, name);
            pst.setString(2, sid);
            pst.setInt(3, age);
            pst.setString(4, course);
            pst.setString(5, department);
            pst.setString(6, tempid);
            result = pst.executeUpdate();
            pst.close();
            if(result > 0) {
                System.out.println("更新成功");
            }
        }catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            con.close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: +1 for avoiding dynamic SQL injection. Also, you removed the comma immediately preceding the WHERE clause, which was the actual cause of the error.